# How can I add a timer to show a design layout for a few seconds and go back in android studio

Tags: android

I need to show a layout(constrainLayout) for a few second and then switch back to the old layout(constrainLayout), these layout are in the same xml file. I have my mainlayout and I have a errorlayout that shows what error I got from the system, I want to show my errorlayout on the screen for like 3 second and than go back to the main layout so the user can keep doing his thing. I tried using sleep methode but I couldn't find how I could do that. I want to do something like u can see down below first make the layouts visible and invisible and then wait for a few second and reverse them back again. this code is just an example

```
        findViewById(R.id.designLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.errorLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView errorcode = findViewById(R.id.errorCode);
        errorcode.setText(message);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        findViewById(R.id.designLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.errorLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: use something like a handler

Comment: Use Handler().postDelayed method for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Handler` for this

```
findViewById(R.id.designLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.errorLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TextView errorcode = findViewById(R.id.errorCode);
errorcode.setText(message);
```

And After this use Handler

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 500ms
        findViewById(R.id.designLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.errorLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
    }, 500);
```